# Rails3 SQL logging output in a separate file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to have all my ActiveRecord SQL logging to have redirected in a different file. It's kinda messy to have it on the console or in the log/development.log.

How to do that? I'd love to have it in a log/development_sql.log file.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('log/development_sql.log')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set it in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/development_sql.log")
```

Comment: Thank you, upvoting. You were 2nd. Excelent.